# creating dmg for python distribution

Tags: python, dmg

So I'm having a little problem here. I'm developing a project on MacOS using python. So far I've created an install that looks like this:

```
python get-pip.py
python ez_setup.py

pip install numpy
pip install scipy
pip install quantities

cd ../../externals
python setup.py install

cd buffet
python setup.py install

cd ../../framework/trunk
python setup.py develop

cd ../../visualiser/trunk
python setup.py develop

cd ../../main/trunk
```

Now this works so far and it installs all my dependencies. All these instructions all set in an install.sh that is located in the main/trunk folder of my project. But I would like to create a dmg to use as distribution. Is this doable ? So far I have my project like:

```
root
    -framework
             -trunk: 
                   -subpackages
    -visualiser
             -trunk
                   -subpackages
    -main
             -trunk (install.sh, run.sh etc.)
```

Now I have little to none experience creating dmg's. What I would like it to put all my distribution in a dmg and when the user installs the project the install.sh script to be automatically called or to incorporate the steps from the install.sh directly into the dmg. Is this possible and if so can you point me to some good tutorials/examples in this area ?

Regards,
Bogdan

Answer (score 2):

I really wonder why you are not using python distutils or setuptools and using an install.sh file.

http://docs.python.org/library/distutils.html

Comment: The project is splitted in 3 big parts as I showed earlier. I am using setuptools for both the framework and the visualiser parts. However numpy and scipy were giving me some problems with disutils that's why I decided to install them with pip. Also I might have to use some dependencies that are not easy_installable like neo .

Comment: Even so say I manage somehow to wrap them alltogether, can setuptools create/help in the creation of dmgs ?